# Not getting Intellisense for Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, lambda, intellisense

Basically, I've created a helper method for a Validation object I'm using. The code is like so:

```
public class ValidationSet<TSource> : ValidationSet
{
    public void AddValidationErrorFor<TProperty>(Expression<Func<TSource, TProperty>> propertyLambda, string errorMessage, string data = null)
    {
        // extension method
        PropertyInfo property = propertyLambda.GetPropertyInfo();

        Add(new ValidationItem
        {
            Key = property.Name,
            Message = errorMessage,
            DataMessage = data
        });
    }
}

public class ValidationSet : List<ValidationItem>
{
    public void AddValidationError(string key, string errorMessage)
    {
        Add(new ValidationItem
        {
            Key = key,
            Message = errorMessage
        });
    }
}
```

Effectively, what happens (and this works), is that I can write something like this:

```
public class SomeObject
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string SomeValue { get; set; }
}
```

And then when I want to validate it, I can write something like this:

```
ValidationSet<SomeObject> validationSet = new ValidationSet<SomeObject>();

if(SomeValue.Contains("SomeOtherValue"))
    validationSet.AddValidatorErrorFor(x => x.SomeValue, "Some Error");
```

This all currently compiles. However, I don't get intellisense for my lambda expression in the last line. I have to manually type `x.SomeValue`, even though it all compiles fine. Does anyone know what is missing to get the intellisense?

Comment: I’ve just run into this bug as well, but found out that it’s not the nullable parameter but just *any* parameter after the lambda expression that causes IntelliSense to stop working. I’ve [filed a bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/789551/intellisense-for-lambda-expressions-passed-to-functions-with-additional-parameters) so maybe something happens here.

Comment: Might be worth noting that I have this same problem cropping up in VS2015 Version 14.0.23107.0 D14REL.  The workarounds in the filed bug (type the , then go back and CTRL+SPACE) seem to work.

Interesting that the bug is supposedly fixed two years ago but remains open .....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reproduced your setup like so...

```
public class ValidateThing<TSource>
{
    public void AddValidation<TProperty>(Expression<Func<TSource, TProperty>> expr)
    {
        //...
    }
}

public static class Tester
{
    public static void Test()
    {
        ValidateThing<string> v = new ValidateThing<string>();

        v.AddValidation(s => s.Length);
    }
}
```

As soon as I typed the `s.` after `s =>`, I got intellisense for the members of `String`. Does this code snippet produce the same behavior as your code?

**EDIT**: Oh, I suppose it's relevant to ask what version of Visual Studio you're using.

Comment: Bingo, found out why there is a problem. The nullable parameter is somehow jacking with the intellisense. As soon as I take that off the signature, it all works as expected. An odd bug, to say the least. Marking this answer as accepted.

Comment: @Tejs That's very interesting. +1 so people notice your response with that. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

IntelliSense in the IDE doesn't have 1-1 parity with code that compiles.  It has to bind expressions based on partially typed structures and hence incomplete information.  This is not always possible to do.

One area which is particularly difficult is IDE inference of lambda expressions (particularly expression trees).  This is likely just a case the IDE doesn't handle well for intellisense

Comment: While possible, how is this different than MVC Html Helper extensions? The source object type is already known, and it has intellisense just fine. AKA HtmlHelper<TController> is similar to ValidationSource<TSource> for my purposes.

Answer (score 1):

@Tejs You got me on the right track.  Although I didn't have a nullable parameter, I did have some extra parameters.  Two of them to be exact.  I removed them and then IntelliSense worked.

So I put them back and created an overloaded version of the extension without the extra parameters and it still worked.

As another test, I commented the extension that had only the one parameter, and verified IntelliSense still worked.  I then added a second parameter to the extension that only had the one parameter, and IntelliSense stopped working.

So in my case at least, I needed a version that only had 1 parameter.

Hope this helps someone else.

Oh and I'm using VS 2015.

Comment: Same problem here. `public static void Set<TObject, TValue>(this TObject obj, Expression<Func<TObject, TValue>> expression, TValue value)`. Adding an overload without the value makes the intelisense work.