# no intellisense suggestion in lambda expression: VS2013, 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense

Suppose I have:

```
public static class Db
{
    public static IDbQueryable<T> Between<T, TKey>(this IDbQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, TKey>> keySelector, int from, int to)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public static IDbQueryable<T> Table<T>()
    {
        return new IDbQueryable<T>();
    }
}

public class IDbQueryable<T>
{
}
public class A
{
    public int C { get; set; }
    IDbQueryable<A> B
    {
        get
        {
            return Db.Table<A>().Between(f => f.C, 0, 5);
        }
    }
}
```

When I type for the first time `return Db.Table<A>().Between(f => f.` visual studio has no suggestion regarding class A properties (B and C), why is that? Could this be fixed? Tried VS 2013 (update 4) and 2015 (update 3).

Here is the pic from VS2015:
[image]

**EDIT**
Doesn't work only when writing the whole line by hand (modifying the old one works).

Writing like this `return Db.Table<A>().Between<A, int>(f => f.)` works.
Related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5475512/579026) suggests VS has problems with expression trees...

**EDIT2**
The problem was due to the fact that there was another `Between` overload not shown here...

Comment: Worked for me on VS 2015 update 2.

Comment: a.C works for me using your code, B needs to be made more accessible in order for it to show.

Comment: @juharr @mxmissile It works if copied and pasted, but try to write the line `return Db.Table<A>().Between(f => f.C, 0, 5);` by hand and you'll see (probably)

Comment: It works for me in VS 2013. If I remove the `C`, it suggests both `B` and `C`.

Comment: Intellisense breaks sometimes. Try Build -> Clean Solution, Build -> Rebuild All. If that doesn't work, restart visual studio.

Comment: @Kelson Ball still same. Does it work for you?

Comment: @ren yes it is working for me. The next thing I would check is if your build is failing silently.

Comment: @Kelson Ball the whole thing compiles, no errors. Weird thing it's working for everyone, I've just tried on a different machine - same crap. Some curse over me.

Comment: @ren If you (change the method signature to) pass the Func directly instead of an Expression do you get intellisense?

Comment: @KelsonBall nope, still same